# incompatible pointer types assigning to uilabel from label view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

i've been doing a thing here using objective-c, but i'm a beginner in this language, and that's what i did:

I've created two UIView class and named them as LabelView and ButtonView. What i wanted to do is when i touch the button the label text changes. I have given the code below which i did.

I get an error when i touch the button i've created.

Error: "-[LabelView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b66cf80"

Warning on the line: self.cslbl_ = lblView; - 
 "incompatible pointer types assigning to uilabel from label view".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

LabelView *lblView = [[LabelView alloc] init];

[lblView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];

//lblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

self.cslbl_ = lblView;

[self.view addSubview:lblView];



ButtonView *btnView = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 200, 100, 50)];

SEL target = @selector(changeText:);

[btnView setSelector:self selector:target];

[self.view addSubview:btnView];

}


-(void) changeText:(UIButton *)btn {

static int k = 0;

if (k%2 == 0)
{
    [self.cslbl_ setText:@"Apple is a healthy fruit"];
}
else
{
    [self.cslbl_ setText:@"Apple"];
}

NSLog(@"Click value is %d",k);

k++;

}
```

Custom Label Class

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self)
{
    UILabel *myLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    myLbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);

    //myLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    myLbl.text = @"Apple";

    self.lbl_ = myLbl;

    [self addSubview:myLbl];
}

return self;
}
```

Custom Button Class

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self)
{
    UIButton *myBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];

    [myBtn setTitle:@"Touch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [myBtn setTitle:@"Touched" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    myBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    self.btn_ = myBtn;

    [self addSubview:myBtn];
}

return self;
}


- (void)setSelector:(UIViewController *)vc selector:(SEL)changeText
{
    [btn_ addTarget:vc action:changeText forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear..what is the type of self.cslbl_?

Comment: What a you mean with self.cslbl_ = lblView.Say please better what a you want to do.Or if you want to do declaration UILabel equal with other UILabel set only cslbl_ = lblView.

Comment: Why are you attempting to subclass `UIView` to create a label and a button? That's what the `UILabel` and `UIButton` classes are for. That error is happening because you're attempting to set the text on your subclass of `UIView` (`LabelView`), which has no idea what to do with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though question is not clear but it seems that your self.cslbl_ is a UILabel and you are assigning lblView to it which of type UIView, thats the reason you are getting warning.

And you are trying to setText to LabelView which is again not a UILabel type that why you are getting crash.

First of all you LabelView should be a subclass of UILabel not UIView but still if its your requirement then you should use below code.

Custom Label Class

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

 if (self)
  {
    UILabel *myLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    myLbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
    [myLb1 setTag:1];
   //myLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    myLbl.text = @"Apple";

    self.lbl_ = myLbl;

    [self addSubview:myLbl];
 }

return self;
}
```

in viewdidload

```
  LabelView *lblView = [[LabelView alloc] init];

  [lblView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];

 self.cslbl_ = (UILabel*)[lblView viewWithTag:1];

 [self.view addSubview:lblView];
```

Now you can set text to your self.cslbl_